# How I can get just the numbers of likes or followers for facebook, twiiter, instagram, snapchat to show it on my html site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, api

I need to know how I can get just the numbers of facebook, twitter, instagram, snapchat pages ( likes or followers ) not facebook plugin box or button I just need the numbers ( the total of likes ).

is that possible?!

Comment: Please read the help section on how to ask a question - this is not a code writing service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this **plugin**

> [jQuery/PHP - Collection of Social Media APIs that display number of
>   your social media fans.](https://github.com/juanv911/SocialCounters)

and it was what I search for.

Thanks anyway